# AppEngine/ComputeEngine: How do I check status of any credit I have?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I got the $2000 bonus from Google a while ago, and I want to check what I have left, and when it's going to expire.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need go to:

https://console.developers.google.com/billing

then you can find here you project.

Click in the project billing.

then you go to Credits tag.

And you can see your credits balance.

---

Google reach you by email 1 month before your credits going to due.

Have fun :)

Comment: That is the form to sign up for the starter pack, it won't help determine the credits left.

Comment: That's not. His answer is correct, I can see on my project my credits left through that way.